# Combining data from different rows into one

Tags: sql

I have a database that looks something like this:

```
col1  | col2 | col3  | col4
User1 | Coms | Start | 19 June 2019
User1 | Coms | Ended | 20 June 2019
```

I would like to transpose the data into a single row, like this:

```
col1  | col2 | col3  | col4          | col5 (end status)
User1 | Coms | Start | 19 June 2019  | Ended
```

You see, this user `Ended` the session, meaning the second row of that transaction is pulled into the first row. If they did not end, the new `End Status` column will simply be a `Null`.

I know there is a function `Stuff ... For XML Path` query that can put some rows together into one comma delimited field, but this is not what I am looking for.

Any good ideas?

Comment: You've specified multiple SQL dialects (MySQL, presto and t-sql) which do you need to achieve this in? The answer will be different for each.

Comment: Will there only ever be two rows per user or might they start and end multiple times?

Comment: @BarneyL comment is very right, which makes this question to "broad".. More or less means that this question is offtopic atleast it is unclear as you are mentioned `Stuff ... For XML Path` which is T-SQL (SQL Server (MSSQL))  syntax, i wonder why that would be wrong as that is T-SQL's method of making dynamic pivot queries, which seams you need here..

Comment: Also i assume user1 records not to be limited to 2 records as this table is a "session based transaction" table?  Showing only 2 records does not give a good idea how your real live data might look like..   The minimal data requirement is giving more then 2 records per "group" and giving more then one group then we have a better understanding you your data looks like around 20 records in total is generally good enough to give us a basic idea to give you more accurate answers...

Comment: @odaysalim . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using -- something someone with your reputation should know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
select col1,col2,
max(case when col3='start' then col3 end),
max(case when col3='end' then col3 end),min(col4)
from table group by col1,col2
```

Answer (score 1):

use conditional aggregation

```
select col1, col2, 
       max(case when col3='Start' then col3 end) as col3,
       max(case when col3='Start' then col4 end) as col4,
       max(case when col3='Ended' then 'Ended' end) as col5
from tablename
group by col1,col2
```